# How to calculate similarity between two sets of items rated on a single dimension?

Tags: regression, distance, distance-functions, cosine-similarity

(I'm just making up variables for this example.)

Let's say I have 100 words rated on their pleasantness.

I also have 100 images rated on their pleasantness.

I then had participants rate the fit between each word and each image.

I want to know if having a similar "pleasantness rating" is predictive of a higher rated fit between words and images.

How would I go about creating a "pleasantness similarity score" for each word-image pair? Would it be enough to standardize word and image ratings, and then take a difference score for each pair? Is there a better way?

Comment: For me, the meaning of 'fit' gets lost in your 'made up' example. Can you elaborate or provide a more meaningful hypothetical example?

Comment: @BruceET On a given trial a person sees a word and a picture, and has to rate how well the word fits the picture, from 1-7. Does that help?